# Too many [options] to choose from

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

There are a lot of questions tagged with [options](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/options). It's extremely meta, and there are no "options" experts that would benefit from a tag like this.

I suggest burninate, and black list.

Comment: Absolutely burn it. This one is as pointless as they come.