# Options tag cleanup now completed

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Looking at the planned [tag cleanup requests](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/status-planned), there is one, [options](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/options), that now has no tagged questions.

So, shouldn't the question:  [Too many [options] to choose from](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9227/too-many-options-to-choose-from)  now be set to status-completed?
It would help focus on those tags that still need to be cleaned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks. Tag has been changed ;)